# Score precision and recall in the multiclass Bayes classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bayesian

I'm a beginner in machine learning and I'm trying to apply a Bayes multiclasses classification algorithm and then do the accurancy score. The first part works, the second part of the calculation does not work but I would like to be able to calculate the degree of precision and recall of the program in its classifications.

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from pprint import pprint
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_files 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

labels = ["price", "personal", "delivery", "store", "product"]
# Download data
docs_to_train = load_files('train')

train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(docs_to_train.data, docs_to_train.target,test_size = 3)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs_to_train.data)

tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf.shape

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape

# Train Bayes classifier
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, docs_to_train.target)

docs_test = ["the shop is beautiful", "the price is expensive", "they are nice the staff",
         "I loved the shop", "there are not many products", "choose the products on the site",
         "more choice in the store", "the packaging is beautiful", "the packaging is very ugly",
         "lack of products", "there are problems on the site", "the shop is very beautiful",
         "the botique is very beautiful", "I love this store", "the pri are not good", "it's expensive",
         "my package did not arrive", "the delivery time is too long", "the cashiers are nice",
         "the value for money is average", "I have not received my order",
         'very disappointed, and I will not come back', 'the delivery is very long',
         "my package did not always arrive", "help sellers to look for a specific product",
         'all very nice and professional cashiers', 'the saleswoman is disagreeable',
         'she's very well advised', 'a little cheaper']

X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_test)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

prediction = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

# print results: it's works!
for doc, category in zip(docs_test, prediction):
    print('COMMENT:', '%r \nLABEL: %s' % (doc, docs_to_train.target_names[category]))
```

> COMMENT: 'the shop is beautiful'
>
> LABEL: delivery
>
> COMMENT: 'the price is expensive'
>
> LABEL: price
>
> COMMENT: 'they are nice the staff'
>
> LABEL: personal
>
> COMMENT: "j'ai adoré le magasin"
>
> LABEL: store
>
> (...)

But the score doesn't work

```
#score
print('Test accuracy is {}'.format(accuracy_score(X_new_tfidf[category], prediction)))
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-5e2d40fed3ab> in <module>()
 85 
 86 #score
---> 87 print('Test accuracy is {}'.format(accuracy_score(X_new_tfidf[category], prediction)))
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
174 
175     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 176     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
177     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):
178         differing_labels = count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py  in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
 69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
 70     """
---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
 72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
 73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
202     if len(uniques) > 1:
203         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 204                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
205 
206 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 29]
```

**I add the data for train:**

**Label: delivery**

delivery with reduced time slot

a little more punctuality for delivery

announce the delivery day and approximate time by sms

to have someone know about his order

reduce delays between order and delivery

watch out for fragile parcels

my package is still not at home

**Label: shop**

I am very unhappy with the organization of the store

I am very happy with your store

enlarge the store

open other shop

regarding this shop everything is perfect

little furniture on display in the shop

**Label: staff**

the friendliness of the seller was very nice

more seller

have more people on the floor to advise us

very good welcome

helpful staff

the employees are nicer than the others

more staff on saturday

and the people who work there are nice

the sellers are super welcoming

the saleswoman did not welcome the customers

**Label: price**

price to go down

lower prices

promotions adapted to my requests

value for money cheaper

almost 50 euros the carpet is expensive

do not increase the price of products

it's not expensive

**Label: product**

reinstate the gift wrapping

I would have liked that gift wrapping

have more stock

check availability of items

furniture availability

more choice in the store

lot of item unavailable

products that work

**REPRODUCTIBLE EXEMPLE**

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from pprint import pprint
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_files 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train = np.array(["prix à baisser",
                "l'amabilité du vendeur était très agréable",
                "baisser les prix",
                "je n'ai pas encore reçu ma commande",
                "plus de vendeur conseil",
                "avoir plus de personnes sur le plancher pour nous conseiller",
                "des promotions adaptées à mes demandes",
                "rapport qualité prix",
                "moins chers",
                "très bonne accueil",
                "durée entre la commande et la livraison assez long",
                "personnel serviable",
                "pratiquement 50 euros le tapis ça fait cher",
                "les employés sont plus gentils les uns que les autres",
                "plus de personnel le samedi",
                "ne pas augmenter le tarif des produits",
                "la remise des produits est en retard",
                "ça vaut le coût",
                "le personnel est parfait mais les produits sont trop chèrs",
                "la somme demandé est correcte et le magasinier était agréable",
                "en plus les gens qu'y travaillent sont sympas",
                "très bon accueil mais le montant des produits sont exorbitant",
                "mon colis n'est pas arrivé"])
y_train_text = [["prix"],["personnel"],["prix"],["livraison"],["personnel"],
            ["personnel"],["prix"],["prix"],["prix"],["livraison"],["personnel"],
            ["personnel"],["prix"],["personnel"],["personnel"],["livraison"],["prix"],["prix"],
            ["personnel", "prix"],["prix", "personnel"],["personnel"],["personnel","prix"],["livraison"]]

X_test = np.array(['un peu moins cher',
               'le passage à la caisse est parfois fort long',
               'il pourrait avoir plus souvent des prix ou offres promotionnels',
               'aide des vendeurs pour chercher un produit spécifique',
               'moins coûteux pour les frais de port',
               'un service de livraison plus compétant',
               'toutes caissières très gentilles et professionnelles',
               'la vendeuse est désagreable',
               'sensibiliser les livreurs aux colis qu?ils transportent',
               'les employés ne connaissaient pas le prix',
               'elle nous a tres bien conseillé'])

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf.shape

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape

# Train Bayes classifier
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train_text)


X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(X_test)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

prediction = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

# print results: it's works!
for doc, category in zip(X_test, prediction):
    print('COMMENT:', '%r \nLABEL: %s' % (doc, y_train_text_names[category]))

print('Test accuracy is {}'.format(accuracy_score(X_new_tfidf[category], prediction)))
```

Comment: the problem is the inputs in `accuracy_score(X_new_tfidf[category], prediction))` should be 2d arrays with same dimensions. Can you add the data ? If not, tell me the shapes of `X_new_tfidf[category]` and `prediction`

Comment: I add the data, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @seralouk No, `accuracy_score` can work with both 1-d array or 2-d array (label-indicator) , but the length of first dimension should be same.

Comment: How are you loading the test files: `docs_test` ? Where have you loaded the labels for this data. You are zipping test docs and their predictions in `'for doc, category in zip(docs_test, prediction)'`, but why are you printing the `docs_to_train.target_names[category]` there which is from train. And lastly, `X_new_tfidf` is a sparse matrix output from `TfidfTransformer`, it will not contain the actual true labels of test docs. So you cannot use that in `accuracy_score`. Can you make a complete reproducible example which we can just copy and run.

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, I loading *docs_test* with a list in the program an I loaded the labels for this data in  *for doc, category in zip(docs_test, prediction)*

Comment: No, you printed that data, and that too wrong data. Can you please make a reproducible example, which I can just copy and paste to get your error?

Comment: @VivekKumar, thank you very much for your explanation about TfidfTransformer! I tried to make it reproducible, but I found other errors. I edited my question. I'm really sorry, but I really am a beginner....

Comment: Ok, now according to the edited question, what I wanted was where;s the `y_test`? You see, for `accuracy_score` you need to have the ground truth (true known labels) of your test data. Only then you can get the accuracy. That is not present in your code here (not even in the edited part). And even the edited part is not reproducible: what's `y_train_text_names` in that?

Comment: **(doc, y_train_text_names[category])** => the test with your label (prediction) and **clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train_text)**: the train and your real label.